# ShrinkWrap Horizontal ListView inside Column with 'mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min' gives error : 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am trying to display a horizontal ListView which height is given by its children inside a Column which height is also this of its children.

However, I'm getting the following error :  'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.

Here is a simple snippet to reproduce the error:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyApp(),
      ),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Vertical1'),
        ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Text('Horizontal1'),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Text('Vertical2')
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As you see the children have a defined height so I don't get the issue.

Here is the expected output:

[image]

I know I can use a SingleChildScrollView but would just like to understand why it does not work with a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your child has a size does not mean the `ListView` will take on that size.
You need to give a height to your `ListView` because by default its height is infinite.

You get this error because you can't place infinite height in a column,
so you give it a height with the widget `Expanded` if you want your list to take all the space available.

Here is an example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('Vertical1')),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: 100,
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Text('Horizontal1'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('Vertical2'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it's not quite what I want. I added a picture so that you could see the expected result.
I understand that ListView has an infinite height by default that's why I used shrinkwrap.

Comment: you want your list having a small height ?

Comment: Yes, the height of the tallest of its children

Comment: ok , at my level i believe that we cant controle size of list view from hes child but i have solution to do that i'll update my code on the post

Comment: ShrinkWrap does not indeed wrap the right direction, what we would need you be a shrinkwrap on the other direction which has you said does not exists.

Comment: yes so we need to bound it i tried with flexible flexfit.loose it doesnt work like you want it still take all the space , so box constrains does the work , you can use sizedBox aswell i think if you get a better solution i wish you can share it with me !

Comment: Well if you go as far as using ContrainBox you wan just use a Container with the right height, which is what I ended up doing even if it's not ideal.